# Debugging individual protractor files with WebStorm

Tags: testing, mocha.js, webstorm, protractor

I want to be able to right click on an individual protractor test, click debug or run and have it execute. I can do this from the command line but I want to be able to debug with WebStorm to leverage the debugger.

By default when right clicking and debugging a file webstorm runs:

```
runnerw.exe "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
--debug-brk=57698 --nolazy myspec.js
```

Can I have it run the following substituting the filename which I've selected:

```
node node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor protractor.dev.conf.js 
--specs "/specs/myspec.js"
```

**As a crappy work around I have the following:**
This runs a single file but I need to edit the configuration each time to change the spec i'm testing.

```
protractor.dev.conf.js --specs "myproject/specs/test0043.js"
```

Does WebStorm allow you to dynamically substitute the test file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do have it run the following substituting the file I've selected: 
>   node node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor protractor.dev.conf.js 
>   --specs "/specs/myspec.js"

and can you run the same not using WebStorm (in command line)? If you can, it's not a problem to do the same in webstorm

Comment: No I've tried it.. It executes it, but it doesn't run the webstorm ide debugger

Answer (score 0):

try ddescribe and iit

iit('should ...')

Will run only those tests marked with iit.

ddescribe will only run the tests under that suite(s)

Try the ddescriber plugin http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7233?pr=phpStorm